# linux + how to stop files creation under /var/spool/clientmqueue

Tags: linux

please advice how to stop the file creation under the directory -

```
     /var/spool/clientmqueue
```

the reason for that because the clientmqeueue folder have huge capacity and files created every day

I verify the folder capacity by du -sh , and folder nearly to 500M

please advice for all possibilities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix this by fixing/removing/killing the application that writes to it. Workarounds like removing the directory or changing its mode just address the symptom, not the root cause.

Comment: please advice if I stop the service sendmail it will also to stop create files in this folder ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change directory permissions by command

> chattr +i  /var/spool/clientmqeueue

By this , no files can be created in this dicretory. if you want to remove protection, just run

> chattr -i  /var/spool/clientmqeueue

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem yesterday,It consumed 40GB of my disk space, **I changed the directory permission of the clientmqueue.** That's it